# VC10 Debugger not working when stepping into unmanaged c++ code from managed c++ code[CLI option]

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, visual-studio-2008, marshalling, unmarshalling

I have managed wrapper over c++ code so that .NET client apps can invoke it. But when I debugg it I can only reach up to the wrapper level. From there I can't step into pure C++ source. 
Flow is as follows

1. CLI option enabled c++ App invokes wrapper interface
2. Step into wrapper source
3. When I try to step into c++ source from there it just skip.

I have built all managaed /unmanaged source involved with Debug info. And also tried with debugger option mixed.But nothing seems to work!

PS : For the time being i am testin it with manager c++, there is no .NET source[client App] involved, only CLR option enabled managed c++ source and pure c++ source.

Comment: Set Debugger type to "Mixed".

Comment: Tried! I thought I already mentioned it.

Comment: Look in the Output window while debugging, it shows whether .pdb files are loaded. This may give some information.

Comment: Checked that too. No such missing pdb error regarding any unmanaged c++ modules.

Comment: This is by design, there are different debug engines involved.  The managed debugger is *very* different from the native code debugger. Single-stepping cannot work, there is no distinct statement where the debugger can figure out that it needs to swap engines.  You need to set a breakpoint instead.  The mode switch occurs when the break triggers.

Comment: +1^ That hit the spot Hans!